# PHP preg_replace returns different value

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have two statement.

1) I **like** Car.
2) I wear cloths **like** king.

In both statement the meaning of like word is different. So I want to write function, If I passed first statement it should return 'a' & I passed second statement then it should return 'b'.

```
    function chkStatement($stmt) {
      //function body
    }
    chkStatement('I like an apple');
chkStatement('I like Mango');
chkStatement('I fly in air like a bird');
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) What do you mean by pass first statement ? What separates statements ?

Comment: Like this statment =  **I like Car**

Comment: you will send separate string each time , then how would chkStatement count the occurance of method call? First of all, you don't need regex here ... you can just see if the string contains the word like or not ... 2ndly you need a global variable to count the number of times the method has been called...

Comment: chkStatement('I like an apple'); this will retrun a.

Comment: chkStatement('I like Mango'); return a. chkStatement('I fly in air like a bird'); return b and so on

Comment: Why chkStatement would return 'a' for I like mango and 'b' for chkStatement , how the method will differ ?

Comment: that is exactly I what I want. In I **like** mango the meaning of **like** is different. And in another statement I fly in air **like** a bird. the meaning of **like** is different. So how could I differentiate these both statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132746/discussion-between-mohan-kute-and-maverick-mrt).

Answer (score 0):

Simple PHP functions like `preg_replace` won't allow you to return different values based on the context in which the word is used.

You will want to look into the vast universe of natural language processing. Good luck!

Comment: Can you Please elaborate more. Or give me any example.

Comment: 1) Just like a bird, i want to fly 2) I like car;          What you return for 1) and what you return for 2) ? For both, the position of like is same but the context is not ... Now how do you detect context , for that you need natural language processing ...

Answer (score 0):

[Marc-Antoine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41561481/5290909) is right, the only way to identify `like` as a verb is with [NLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_programming).

However, if we simplify this enough, you could check for `I`, `You`, `We`, or `They`, before the word `like`. You wouldn't be checking if it's in fact a verb, and there should be lots of exceptions. You could use something like this:

```
function chkStatement($stmt) {
    if (preg_match('/\b(?:(I|You|We|They)\s+)?like\b/i', $stmt, $matches)) {
        if (isset($matches[1])) return "a";
        return "b";
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

echo chkStatement('I like an apple');
echo chkStatement('I like Mango');
echo chkStatement('I fly in air like a bird');
echo chkStatement('Something else');
```